# How do I capture when a date is tapped in SwiftUI `DatePicker`?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to send a network request whenever the user has chosen a new date from the DatePicker. How do I capture that event?

`onChange` does this on iOS 14. Still haven’t found iOS 13

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### SwiftUI 2

You can use `onChange`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate)
                .onChange(of: selectedDate) {
                    print($0)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI 1

Use `onReceive` instead:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate)
                .onReceive(Just(selectedDate)) {
                    print($0)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `onReceive` fires also when a view is initialised.

Comment: Thank you. That is for iOS14 only. What is the iOS 13 solution?

Comment: @MarcusZiadé Added a solution for iOS 13.